# make function wait for a promise to return nodejs

Tags: node.js, q

I am using Q library and would like to make the promise2 function to wait until the promise1 function has finished execution.

In the following example the promise2 function gets executed before the promise1 function finishes execution.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var Q = require("q");
var fs = require('fs');

function promise1() {
  var deferred = new Q.defer();
  fs.readFile('hostname.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err){
      return  console.error(err)
    }else {
      console.log('file read');
      return deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
function promise2(){
  var deferred = new Q.defer();
   var path = 2;
    console.log("2");
  return deferred.resolve(path);
}

Q(promise1())
  .then(promise2());
```

here is the working example, might give errors since the readfile does not exist, but it does exists in my dev environment.

```
I get the following result when I run:
>2
>file read

Result I want:
>file read 
>2
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write `promise2()` you execute it immediately. Try:

`promise1().then(promise2);`

Comment: so should it be Q(promise1()).then(promise2);

Comment: The `Q()` is superfluous to my understanding. But when javascript sees a method invocation, `()`, it executes the function. In your original case, in order to resolve the call to `.then()` you passed in the function call instead of the function definition. You can give their documentation a thorough read through [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).